# Hash key retrieval in ruby with .key? method

Tags: ruby

I am trying to retrieve and print the value for a certain key in Ruby but it won't work. I have the following set and get methods:

```
attr_accessor :data_hash

def initialize
    @data_hash = Hash.new
end

def set(arrayInfo, value)
    full_key = Command.new(arrayInfo[1],arrayInfo[2],arrayInfo[3],arrayInfo[4],value)
    data_hash.store(arrayInfo[1],full_key)
    return "Key Stored"
end

def get(name)
    if(data_hash.key?(name.to_s.to_sym)) then
        return data_hash[name]
    else
        return 'Key not in hash'
    end
end
    
def gets(key)
    return data_hash
end
```

*Note I added the to_s.to_sym as I saw in a previous answer that might be the problem, but neither with this nor without it works

The value is stored as an object Command with the following class:

```
class Command
 
      attr_accessor :key, :flag, :time, :bytes, :value

      def initialize(key, flag, expTime, bytes,value)
          @key = key
          @flag = flag
          @expTime = expTime
          @bytes = bytes
          @value = value
      end
end
```

And although the value is being stored successfully as you may see here, when I try getting it in the get() function, it goes straight to the else condition. Here is what i get in the command prompt:

```
>set John 2 2 2
>Doe
-Key Stored
>get John
-Key not in hash
>gets John
-{"John"=>#<Command:0x0000000006468970 @key="John", @flag="2", @expTime="2", @bytes="2", @value="Doe">}
```

Comment: You are converting the key to a symbol before looking it up, but as you can clearly see from the output, the keys are strings, not symbols.

Comment: What is `set John 2 2 2\nDoe` supposed to be? I guess this is actually `set ["John", 2, 2, 2], "Doe"`, but you're not making our lives easy by omitting key syntax like that.

Comment: You are storing the hash key with whatever data type the first element is -- apparently it's a string, `"John"`? And then for some reason you're converting the lookup value to a `Symbol` (`name.to_s.to_sym`) -- and it fails to find a key with that value. Strings and Symbols are different objects in ruby. `"John" != :John`. That's why your code fails.

Comment: It does not work without the (.to_s.to_sym) neither. I added that because I thought that's how you look up strings inside hashes. But without that conversion and just using the .key? with the normal name it does not work.
How should I look for this key?